# Saving PDF with Devdefined's IConsumerRequest

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, devdefined-oauth

I'm trying to save a PDF from QBO however I'm stuck on this bit:
How do i get the IConsumerRequest to return a stream instead of a string?  ReadBody only seems to send string rather than binary data...

```
IConsumerRequest conReq = oSession.Request();
conReq = conReq.Get().WithRawContentType("application/pdf");
string outURL = base_url + "invoice-document/v2/" + realmId + "/" + customerInvoicesWithinDateRange[0].Id.Value;
conReq = conReq.ForUrl(outURL);
conReq = conReq.SignWithToken();
string serviceResponse = conReq.ReadBody();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of conReeq.ReadBody(), you can do this:

```
conReq.ToWebResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

in fact, ReadBody() is simply an extension method on IConsumerRequest, defined as:

```
public static string ReadBody(this IConsumerRequest request)
{
  HttpWebResponse response = request.ToWebResponse();

  return response.ReadToEnd();
}
```